# localStorage.getItem() does not return null when the key doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to check if a key exists in the `localStorage` in JavaScript. I've searched for an answer online and I've found that the method `getItem` will return `null` if the key does not exist.

This is the code I've been using:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('token') !== null) {
    return <div className="inform-text">Placeholder</div>
    }
else {
    return <div className="inform-text">Sign In</div>
    }
```

But it always returns the Placeholder div, meaning it's always true. When I run `console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'))`, it doesn't return `null` but instead a blank space like: ''. I could of course change the `null` to `''` in the if statement but I'm curious as to why this is happening.

Comment: How have you made sure that there really is no `token` in local storage? "*When I run console.log(localStorage.getItem('token')), it doesn't return null but instead a blank space like*" sounds like you have a blank string stored.

Comment: You've probably set it to `setItem("token", "")` somewhere. Run `localStorage.removeItem("token")` in the console and try again

Comment: That's exactly it, had set it to that blank string in another file by accident. Thanks to both of you, it works perfectly now!

Comment: @Alejandro, That is bad advice. The good advice is to call `removeItem`.

Comment: @AlejandroSalamancaMazuelo not going to work. `"" != null` gives the same result as `"" !== null`. Only `null` and `undefined` are `==` to `null`. https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/